# it is possible to put ubuntu on my htc wildfire s? and how?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a htc wildfire s it is rooted but is it possible to get ubuntu on my phone? If so, how?

I am not so smart with this so please if it is possible a full tutorial?

Answer (score 3):

No,

Your phone does not meet the minimum specifications.
It currently only supports a limited number of devices, the 
Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4,7 and 10

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames